# What is the best way for a JVM-based program to embed and interop with WASM?

Tags: jvm, webassembly

We are investigating supporting the WASM compilation target in the extensions framework of an existing JVM-based application. Is there a well-supported JVM-based way to load and run WASM? Does any SDK include developer tooling for compatibility between WASM and JVM?

I know there are a lot of related questions that can make this a subjective question. Please focus just on whether it is possible, and how.